# Strange characters in Arraylist

Tags: android, json, arraylist

Hello i am facing a problem here. I have a [JSON String](http://my.chatapp.info/quiz/getf.php?id=3) and i parse data like this:

```
@Override
        protected List<QuestionsList> doInBackground(String... params) {
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                setupDataToDB();
                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
                bufferedWriter.write(StringGenerator.queryResults(nameValuePairs));
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                jsonResult = StringGenerator.inputStreamToString(inputStream, QuestionsActivity.this);
                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult.toString());
                Log.e("Response: ", jsonResult.toString());
                checkDisplayLanguage(langText);
                questionsLists = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                    jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    questionName = jsonChildNode.optString(Constants.QUESTION_NAME_JSON_NAME);
                    Log.e("Question Name: ", questionName);
                    jsonArray = jsonChildNode.optJSONArray(Constants.QUESTIONS_ANSWERS_ARRAY);
                    question_answers = new ArrayList<>();
                    question_iscorrect = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                        jsonSecondChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        answer1 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("answer1");
                        Log.e("Answer1", answer1);
                        answer2 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("answer2");
                        Log.e("Answer2", answer2);
                        answer3 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("answer3");
                        Log.e("Answer3", answer3);
                        iscorrect1 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("iscorrect1");
                        iscorrect2 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("iscorrect2");
                        iscorrect3 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("iscorrect3");
                        question_answers.add(answer1);
                        question_answers.add(answer2);
                        question_answers.add(answer3);

                        question_iscorrect.add(iscorrect1);
                        question_iscorrect.add(iscorrect2);
                        question_iscorrect.add(iscorrect3);

                        Log.e("Answers in for loop", question_answers.toString());
                        questionsLists.add(new QuestionsList(questionName, question_answers, question_iscorrect));
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return questionsLists;
        }
```

and they output like this:

```
E/Question Name:: Where to look to find journal articles
E/Answers in for loop: [In the librarys catalog , , ]
E/Answers in for loop: [In the librarys catalog , , , , In alphabetical list of healink , ]
E/Answers in for loop: [In the librarys catalog , , , , In alphabetical list of healink , , , , Databases available in the library's site]
E/Question Name:: What information we provide magazine
E/Answers in for loop: [Published research experiments current information, , ]
E/Answers in for loop: [Published research experiments current information, , , , Lists information about people, addresses, organizations, ]
E/Answers in for loop: [Published research experiments current information, , , , Lists information about people, addresses, organizations, , , , Legislation, competitions]
E/Question Name:: What is the Issn (International Standard Serial Number)
E/Answers in for loop: [Is the number used for the registration of periodical publications, , ]
E/Answers in for loop: [Is the number used for the registration of periodical publications, , , , Is the International Unique number used for registration of printed books, ]
E/Answers in for loop: [Is the number used for the registration of periodical publications, , , , Is the International Unique number used for registration of printed books, , , , Is the International Unique number used for the recording of Publications mixed forms]
```

i want to be displayed like this:

```
E/Answers in for loop: [Is the number used for the registration of periodical publications, Is the International Unique number used for registration of printed books, Is the International Unique number used for the recording of Publications mixed forms]
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You quesition is not clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing the data in a wrong way, the second for loop is redundunt and it's also the reason for your data being displayed wrong.

Basically on every iteration you pulling the answer on the i'th place, since there is no data for the 2nd and the 3rd place on the first iteration the 1st and 2nd place on the array (hence second and third since the array is zero based) are empty on the first time, on the second iteration the 3rd and 4th (hence fourth and fifth) are empty and only the 6th had data and so on...

In case you will always get 3 answers you can remove the for loop and just address the 0, 1, 2 locations on the array to get the answers - That will do the job.

In case you want it to be more generic way switch it to the code below -

```
 for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
            jsonSecondChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            answer = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("answer" + (j+1));
            Log.e("Answer", answer);
            iscorrect = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("iscorrect" + (j+1));
            question_answers.add(answer);
            question_iscorrect.add(iscorrect);

            Log.e("Answers in for loop", question_answers.toString());
        }
```

Also this line:

```
questionsLists.add(new QuestionsList(questionName, question_answers, question_iscorrect));
```

Should be outside of both the for loops, since only there the gathering the data is done...

Comment: ok after make it your way it works but now in post execute i do this:
`answersArray = lists.get(position).getAnswers();
            for (int pos = position; pos<answersArray.size();pos++){
                ans1 = answersArray.get(pos);
                ans2 = answersArray.get(pos);
                ans3 = answersArray.get(pos);
            }`
and it always gets the last item? how can i fix it?

Comment: If my first answer helped you you can accept it, secondly - you are doing the same mistake over here again..you dont have to use a for loop..

Answer (score 1):

In the Setter if you have one do the following:

```
void setAnswer (String sAnswer)
{
 String myAnswer = sAnswer.replace ("[", ""); 
}
```